# Can't get the where clause in Select layer by attribute working!

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, arcgis-10.0

I am trying to develop a script that searches for a particular ID in a user selected field. To this end I have used the select layer by attributes tool to search for a derived number in a field specified by the user.I cannot, however, after numerous attempts, get the where clause right. I have posted my latest attempt below:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

work_space = "L:\\DRAINAGE\\D_GROUP6\\STAFF\\CJE\\EDRNb\\EDRN_holding.gdb"

env.workspace = work_space

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

selected_li = "L:\\DRAINAGE\\D_GROUP6\\STAFF\\CJE\\EDRN_holding.gdb\\EDRN7\\EDRN_LINK"
OB_ID = "OBJECTID_1"

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(selected_li)
for row in rows:
    id_LCC = row.getValue(OB_ID)
    id_TNDE = row.getValue("TO_DRNNODE")
    if id_TNDE == " " or id_TNDE == None:
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(selected_li, "feature_layer10") 
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("feature_layer10", "NEW_SELECTION", '"' + str(OB_ID) + '" =' + "'" + str(id_LCC) + "'")
```

So, if anyone has any ideas please do let me know.

Comment: To check for null you should use id_TNDE is None, not id_TNDE == None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we print out your formatted string we get this:
'"OB_ID" =\'id_LCC\''

This is not what you want. Format considerations for file GDBS are as follows:

- Field names are not qouted
- If the value is a string, use single quotes
- If the value is a number, do not use quotes
- [Review the help docs for more details](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/SQL_reference_for_query_expressions_used_in_ArcGIS/00s500000033000000/)

Use .format to simplify the variable substitution

The query format should be:

```
"{} = '{}'".format(OB_ID,ID_LCC)
```